# Why Index-Only-Scan's COST can be higher than Seq-Scan

Tags: postgresql, index

```
sql> create table index_test (col1 integer, col2 integer default 0);
sql> do $$
  begin
  for i in 1..100000 loop
    insert into index_test (col1) values(i);
  end loop;
end;
$$;

sql> create index p_index_test2 on index_test (col1, col2);

sql> explain analyze select col2 from index_test where col1 > 40000;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                      |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Seq Scan on index_test  (cost=0.00..1693.00 rows=59718 width=4) (actual time=2.916..426.669 rows=60000 loops=1) |
|   Filter: (col1 > 40000)                                                                                        |
|   Rows Removed by Filter: 40000                                                                                 |
| Planning time: 0.104 ms                                                                                         |
| Execution time: 829.769 ms                                                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


sql> SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
sql> explain analyze select col2 from index_test where col1 > 40000;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Index Only Scan using p_index_test2 on index_test  (cost=0.29..1705.36 rows=59718 width=4) (actual time=0.032..427.644 rows=60000 loops=1) |
|   Index Cond: (col1 > 40000)                                                                                                               |
|   Heap Fetches: 0                                                                                                                          |
| Planning time: 0.076 ms                                                                                                                    |
| Execution time: 839.303 ms                                                                                                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The above is comparing two query plan. one is using `Index-Only-Scan` the other is using `Seq-Scan`.

At the fist, I expected that query planner uses `Index-Only-Scan` for sure. 
However, the two plan show similar cost and actual time figure and it even shows `Index-Only-Scan` is more expensive.

Why?

I know that in case of `Index-Scan`, it needs additional action fetching data from data table so that the `Index-Scan`'s cost could be more expensive than `Seq-Scan` but this is not in the case of `Index-Only-Scan`.

One thing my assumpting is because the cardinality of result is hight(40001~100000). I think high cardinality could make planner do many random-access and its cost is higher than sequential-access.

However, I think planner will use sequential-access(not random-access) because `WHERE` clause is range-condition and index is always ordered.

---

### Edit

Postgresql 10.5

As I understand, If it simplifies, the two plan will work like the below.

---

with `Index-Only-Scan`

1. move to 40001
2. read data sequentially up to 100000

cast = `(jump to 40001 in index table) + (read 60000 sequentially in index table)`

---

with `Seq-Scan`

1. read data sequentially up to 100000

cast = `(read 100000 sequentially in data table)`

---

If the two plan have similar coat, it means `(jump to 40001 in index table)`'s cost is expensive as `(read 40000 sequentially in data table)`

Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Performance questions *need* the Postgres version in use. And typically more ...

Comment: The default index fill factor is 90%, while the table fill factor is 100%, so in theory the optimizer might expect to read up to 10% more pages when scanning the index _in your scenario_.

Comment: Your understanding is basically right. But you seem to under-estimate the overhead added by index access methods.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter not sure if you're addressing me or the OP. I'm just pointing out the elephant in the room; there might also be mice and other rodents in that room, contributing their 0.36. Do you know for a fact that the optimizer (we're looking at estimates here) considers "the overhead added by index access methods"?

Comment: @mustaccio: Comments without `@` address the OP. We can see from the cost estimates in the query plans that some overhead is accounted for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in timing you show is below noise level and does not tell us more than that both query plans are about as fast - which is as expected.

You do seem to test on a terribly slow system, though. This simple query shouldn't take close to a second. Even on my age-old laptop, this takes below 20 ms. Either you are on ancient / minimal hardware or your server configuration might need some attention. Very old Postgres version, too, maybe?

You added Postgres 10.5, which was released 2018-08-09. The current minor release is 10.10. [The Postgres project recommends:](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

> We always recommend that all users run the latest available minor release for whatever major version is in use.

While selecting ~ 60 % of the table, with a row width of only 8 user-bytes (36 bytes total), not even an index-only scan on a pristine index without bloat (based on the same row size!) has much to offer over a sequential scan. There is just not much left to make this faster than reading sequentially and filtering 40%.

B-tree indexes have a smaller row header than the heap (8 vs. 24 bytes), but [a fillfactor of 90 %](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) by default. And indexes tend to bloat more and quicker than tables. Plus, the various index access methods all add some overhead. For an index-only scan Postgres needs to first read and evaluate the [visibility map](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-vm.html).

Test with much smaller percentages, wider table rows, higher cardinalities, including toasted columns, etc. Throw in some table and/or index bloat, and you'll get more interesting results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I sill don't understand, could you check my edited question?

Comment: The reason that `index-only-scan` need to check `visibility map` is because the index-table could still contain deleted data?

Comment: @asleea: Yes, deleted, yet uncommitted or updated rows. Indexes to not contain visibility information, so all index access methods have to recheck by going to the heap (main relation). Index-only scans are the exception, but only allowed for data pages that are all-visible. The manual has more, follow [the link I provided.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-vm.html)

Comment: Thank you !! Could you answer one more question? [this link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-index-only-scans.html) is saying `whether all rows stored in that page are old enough to be visible to all current and future transactions.`. does `old enough` mean that it is enough time to run `vacuum` already?

Comment: "Old enough" is a metaphor for "transaction ID < smallest transaction ID of any open transaction". ’VACUUM’ is required to actually update the vm (among other things).